# Changing fragment layout from a thread that works in activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I have an activity that contains fragments that are added at runtime. Also activity is connected to the tcp server. When I swipe the fragment server sends a message in a different thread. Then I want to change the button colors inside the fragment in this thread. I have written the code in fragment below:

```
public class changeBtn implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button = (Button) fragmentView.findViewWithTag("Button1");
    }
}
public void startProg(String[] array)
{
   new Thread(new changeBtn()).start();
}
```

This is the class that works async in activity for tcp

```
 public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    srvrMessage = message;
                    if(srvrMessage!=null&&message!=null) {
                        acikMasalar = srvrMessage.split("\\*");
                        mesajGeldi = true;
                        FragmentMasaDesing fragment=null;
                        if(mesajGeldi) {
                            int a =mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                            fragment = (FragmentMasaDesing) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                    .getFragments().get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                        }
                        if(fragment!=null) {
                            fragment.startProg();

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am running this code inside the thread that works in activity. It throws me this error:"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

How can I change the button color from another thread in activity?

Comment: the thread is not started in the ui thread of your activity. Start another thread in UI thread

Comment: Do you mean that I should open a new thread in activity and run this thread in my message received thread and activity thread should trigger fragment.startProg();?

Comment: I dont mean that I mean to update an activity you need to do it in either the main or UI thread or you need to call a thread from the main thread of the same activity